# Why does new Number(2) != new String("2") in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

The following evaluate to `true`:

```
new Number(2) == 2
new String("2") == "2"
```

Obviously, but so do the following:

```
"2" == 2
new Number(2) == "2"
new String("2") == 2
```

So can someone explain clearly why he following evaluates `false`?

```
new Number(2) == new String("2")
```

Comment: Implicit type coercian explains the "2" == 2 examples

Comment: @dougajmcdonald: Nope.

Comment: You created two objects and are trying to compare them. In such an instance, `==` will compare references rather than use type conversion. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_(.3D.3D)

Comment: Equality on object-to-object tests for identity; equality on object to most primatives (except booleans?) tests the stringified forms of both operands.

Comment: @apsillers: It's much more complicated than that. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right I forgot that we stringify the object and then number-ify the string, if the other operand is a number. I thought I'd done enough "step through the Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm" answers to have it memorized by now; alas, no. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because JavaScript has both *primitive* and *object* versions of numbers and strings (and booleans). `new Number` and `new String` create *object* versions, and when you use `==` with object references, you're comparing object references, not values.

`new String(x)` and `String(x)` are fundamentally different things (and that's true with `Number` as well). *With* the `new` operator, you're creating an object. *Without* the `new` operator, you're doing type coercion — e.g. `String(2)` gives you `"2"` and `Number("2")` gives you `2`.

Comment: Ahh, so `new String("2") == new String("2")` is `false` along with `new Number(2) == new Number(2)`

Answer (score 1):

What I think `==` is basically does value comparision.

In above all situations it's comparing just values. But in this one

```
new Number(2) == new String("2")
```

Both are objects so it doesn't compare values, it tries to compare values of object references. That's why it returns `false`.

Comment: To be more accurate: It's still comparing values. The values being compared are object references.

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
new Number(2) == new Number(2)
```

that returns

> false

and you will have the answer: there are 2 different objects that have 2 different references.